# How to fix Android Studio Emulator rotated/stretched display

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am running "Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2" on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

The emulator was working fine, then at some point it got into a weird state:
[Emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9IWp.png)
[Emulator rotated 90 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOiwW.png)

Restarting Android Studio does not fix the issue.

I tried restarting the emulator.
I closed the project and restarted Android studio.
The issue remains.